# How to check that a given matrix is a perfect square?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose we have a $2\times2$ matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$  with integer entries. We know that if $det(A) < 0$ then it can't be a perfect square. Another necessary condition is that $det(A)$ must be a perfect square. Does there exist any method to determine whether $A$ is a perfect square, i.e. does there exist a matrix $B = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & b_1 \\ c_1 & d_1 \end{bmatrix}$  with integer entries such that $B^2 = A.$ We need not calculate $B$ in particular, we just need to show that either $A$ is a perfect square or not a perfect square.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342049/positive-integer-2-times-2-matrix-with-two-positive-integer-square-root-matric